# convert pgsql int array into python array

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, psycopg2

I have numeric data (int) stored in pgsql as arrays. These are `x,y,w,h` for rectangles in an image e.g. `{(248,579),(1,85)}`

When reading to my python code (using psycopg) I get it as a string (?). I am now trying to find the best way to obtain a python array of ints from that string. 
Is there a better way than to split the string on ',' and so on...

p.s. I did try `.astype(int)` construct but that wouldn't work in this instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you wouldn't be able to change the input format, you could remove any unneeded characters, then split on the `,`'s or do the opposite order.

```
data = '{(248,579),(1,85)}'
data.translate(None, '{}()').split(',')
```

will get you a list of strings.

And

```
[int(x) for x in data.translate(None, '{}()').split(',')]
```

will translate them to integers as well.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was hoping to go thus route, hoping there was a more elegant way of doing this python-side. Unfortunately the pgq schema is locked. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the rectangle is stored in Postgresql as an array of points:

```
query = '''
    select array[(r[1])[0],(r[1])[1],(r[2])[0],(r[2])[1]]::int[]
    from (values ('{"(248,579)","(1,85)"}'::point[])) s (r)
'''

cursor.execute(query)
print cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Returns a Python int list

```
[248, 579, 1, 85]
```

Notice that while a Postgresql array is base 1 by default, a `Point` coordinate is retrieved as a base 0 array.